# Access parent of Loader - how?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I have:

```
myMovieClip = new MovieClip();
myMovieClip.myLoader = new Loader();
```

This goes for a number of MovieClips. Later, I need to be able to refer back to the parent MovieClip from the Loader itself (because it happens in an event triggered by the Loader finishing loading). "evt.target.loader.parent" doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

with loaders you'll be able to define complete and error events.

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoaderComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderError);
```

from those functions, if they are handled by the parent class you speak of you are already scoped to the parent object, so you can call all those methods in the callbacks you define.